# Selecting all akka actors in a subtree with ActorSelection wildcard

Tags: akka, wildcard, actor

The akka documentation explains how it is possible to use wildcards when using ActorSelection (http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html#Querying_the_Logical_Actor_Hierarchy).

The following code will send a message to all actors *directly* under `/user`

```
context.actorSelection("/user/*") ! msg
```

Is it possible to use a wildcard that would send a message to all descendants (not only direct children) in an actor hierarchy? I have tried the following code, without success:

```
context.actorSelection("/**") ! msg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we do not support "send to all descendants, however many levels deep". I feel that this could easily lead to unexpected behaviour and may be overused. You can do something similar, but with specifying the depth of the search, as in:

```
val top = system.actorOf(p, "a")
val b1 = Await.result((top ? Create("b1")).mapTo[ActorRef], timeout.duration)
val b2 = Await.result((top ? Create("b2")).mapTo[ActorRef], timeout.duration)
val c = Await.result((b2 ? Create("c")).mapTo[ActorRef], timeout.duration)
val d = Await.result((c ? Create("d")).mapTo[ActorRef], timeout.duration)

system.actorSelection("/user/a/*/c/*").tell(Identify(6), probe.ref)
probe.expectMsg(ActorIdentity(6, Some(d)))
probe.expectNoMsg(200.millis)
```

Also, actor selection is possibly not what you're after and instead you could use something that's dedicated for broadcasting like that;

You could use the [EventStream](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/scala/event-bus.html) and publish your broadcast there.

Or if you're in a clustered env use the [DistributedPubSub extension](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.4/contrib/distributed-pub-sub.html) (here's an activator template with it: [akka-clustering (pubsub) activator template](https://typesafe.com/activator/template/akka-clustering))

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I am really new to akka. I have also looked at EventBus and managed to use it in a simple example. On that topic, I was wondering if there are restrictions/opinions on the number of subscribers for a topic. If I write a simulation app and have millions of actors, does it make sense to have each one of them subscribed on the EventBus? Or is that a bad practice?

Comment: We've seen people use event buses way, I can't give concrete numbers at this point, but it's more or less as fast as actor message sends. Start out by using it, and if in trouble - profile your app and find what's not keeping up. Feel free to ask on akka-user or here if that happens :)